# displaying v-progress-circular in a conditional is making the below elements "jumpy"

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

The progress circle will be there until the codition `sending` is false. what happens is that after the dive goes away the below element will jump up to where the div dissapeared making it seem "jumpy". What would be the best way to display it in a stable manner.

```
        <v-progress-circular
          color="#64B5F6"
          indeterminate
        ></v-progress-circular>
      </div>
    //rest of stuff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you are using `v-if="sending"` on the parent `<div>`.  When `sending==false` the `v-if` directive will completely remove it from the DOM.  You can't even use `v-show` because although this will keep it in the DOM, it will have `"display: none"` css so it it still wont take up any space.

Instead, you need to set the `visibility: hidden` css to hide the spinner without collapsing the space it takes up.

You can do this in two ways:

```
<div :style="{visibility: sending ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}">
   <v-progress-circular ...>
<div>
```

Or, create a re-usable [custom directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html):

```
Vue.directive('visible', function(el, binding) {
    el.style.visibility = !!binding.value ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
});
```

Then use it like so:

```
<div v-visible="sending">
   <v-progress-circular ...>
<div>
```